# MS Access VBA improve script

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures, vba

I have this code in MS Access (I did it in VBA becasue I didn't find the way to create a **procedure** in Access). What it does is simple, it takes a field form a table and replace the value in another table where the ID is the same.

How can I get this faster? It is currently taking 8 minutes more or less to get it done (processor is always under 20%, so it is not about processor power).

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tab_personal_2")

 rst.MoveFirst

 DoCmd.SetWarnings False

 Do Until rst.EOF
    DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE Tab_personal_3 SET RFC = '" & rst("RFC") & "' WHERE Id = " & rst("Id"))
    rst.MoveNext

 Loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this in a single query:

```
UPDATE Tab_personal_3 t3
INNER JOIN Tab_personal_2 t2 ON t2.ID = t3.ID
SET t3.RFC = t2.RFC
```

Of course, you can execute this query through VBA, if you wish. But storing the query allows Access to store the execution plan, and increase the speed on the query.

Comment: Thanks, forgot the possibility of inner join when update

Answer (score 0):

I believe a single update query will work if the tables share an ID field:

```
UPDATE Tab_personal_3 INNER JOIN Tab_personal_2 ON Tab_personal_3.ageing_collection = Tab_personal_2.Id SET Tab_personal_3.RFC = Tab_personal_2.RFC;
```